# Cannot set boot-args even with SIP disabled

Tags: macos, startup, big-sur, sip, nvram

I have installed macOS Big Sur as a guest system in Parallels Desktop 16. I disabled SIP. However, I'm still unable to change nvram values for boot-args. Is there another security feature that I haven't disabled?

```
>sudo -i
>csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
>nvram boot-args="amfi_get_out_of_my_way=0x1" 
nvram: Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) general error
>nvram test=test
>nvram test
test    test
>nvram boot-args
nvram: Error getting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) data was not found
```

Comment: Not sure, but there’s an added layer in Big Sur, which is the signed (sealed) system volume. As to how it works and how to disable, I am not yet familiar with but google SSV Big Sur and you should find some information about it

Comment: @AVelj That is filesystem protection, which should have nothing to do with nvram. nvram is protected by SIP only in previous versions (`csrutil enable --without nvram`).